# How do I store Kubernetes configuration in same repository as code?

Tags: git, docker, kubernetes, containers

I currently have a GitHub repository that contains my application code and a Kubernetes deployment configuration file (called `deployment.yml`). I.e., my repository has the following structure:

```
repository
  +- ...application code...
  +- Dockerfile
  \- deployment.yml
```

When a change is pushed to this GitHub repository, a series of GitHub Actions are executed that containerize my application into a Docker image and publish that image to Docker Hub.

On a development machine, I have a Kubernetes cluster running. I pull the `deployment.yml` file from the repository and either apply that configuration using `kubectl apply -f deployment.yml` or perform a rolling-update using `kubectl rollout restart deployment/<name>`.

My `deployment.yml` is configured as follows:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  ...
spec:
  replicas: 1
  ...
  template:
    ...
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: <name>
        image: foo/bar:v1.0.0
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        ports:
          - containerPort: <port>
      imagePullSecrets:
      - name: <creds-id>
```

The version of the image (i.e., `v1.0.0` in `foo/bar:v1.0.0`) originates from the tags I use in Git. I.e., if I tag a commit as `v1.0.0`, a new build is run for that tag and a new Docker image is published to Docker Hub with the tag `v1.0.0`.

My problem is that I am storing my Kubernetes configuration (`deployment.yml`) in the same repository that is being tagged. This means that I am tagging a commit (i.e., `v2.0.0`) that contains an image of `foo/bar:v1.0.0` in the `deployment.yml`. I.e., I make changes to my code and then decide once those changes are sufficient, that a specific commit will be tagged. Since I want the cluster on my development machine to use the latest, approved (i.e., tagged) code, I then go an update the `deployment.yml` and commit, but that new commit is after the tagged commit.

To resolve this, I would have to change the `deployment.yml` file for the commit I know will be tagged. I.e., knowing that the next commit I make will be tagged as `v2.0.0`, I will have to change the `deployment.yml` to use the image `foo/bar:v2.0.0` and add that change to the commit (i.e., the one to be tagged). In that case, the commit tagged as `v2.0.0` will have an image of `foo/bar:v2.0.0` in its `deployment.yml`.

Is there a technique or best practice (such as templating or another practice) that can solve this issue?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Helm** templating is also a good option however if your project is basic and won't be much requirement there use this basic method keeping the **deployment.yaml** in repo simple way.

Ideally, you can keep your **deployment** file dynamic as much as possible rather than fix values to the add-in.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1beta2
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: test-image
  labels:
    app: test-image
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: test-image
      tier: frontend
  strategy:
    type: RollingUpdate
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: test-image
        tier: frontend
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: TEST_IMAGE_NAME
        name: test-image
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
          name: http
        - containerPort: 443
          name: https
```

and in the **YAML** **CI** config we change the **IMAGE URL** in deployment.yaml file as per need.

`Google could build` CI file example, however you can write or update the logic in your **YAML** CI

```
steps:
- id: 'set test core image in yamls'
  name: 'ubuntu'
  args: ['bash','-c','sed -i "s,TEST_IMAGE_NAME,gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/$REPO_NAME/$BRANCH_NAME:$SHORT_SHA," deployment.yaml']
```

In your process, the **YAML** file and run time replace the string with **URL** you want to add.

**Git** will give you necessary variables like **COMMIT HASH** or **TAGGED VERSION**.

Example **CI** file **YAML** file,

```
steps:
- id: 'build test core image'
  name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
  args: ['build', '-t', 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/$REPO_NAME/$BRANCH_NAME:$SHORT_SHA', '.']
- id: 'push test image'
  name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
  args: ['push', 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/$REPO_NAME/$BRANCH_NAME:$SHORT_SHA']
- id: 'set test core image in yamls'
  name: 'ubuntu'
  args: ['bash','-c','sed -i "s,TEST_IMAGE_NAME,gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/$REPO_NAME/$BRANCH_NAME:$SHORT_SHA," deployment.yaml']
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/kubectl'
  args: ['apply', '-f', 'deployment.yaml']
```

inside your `deployment.yaml` there will be one string `TEST_IMAGE_NAME` which will get replaced during the `CI` operation

using simple ubuntu command **sed** : `sed -i "s,TEST_IMAGE_NAME,gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/$REPO_NAME/$BRANCH_NAME:$SHORT_SHA," deployment.yaml`

variables like `$SHORT_SHA` will get auto injected or added by **Github** so now on your **CI server** you have one `deployment.yaml` with `Image-URL` that you have pushed to docker hub.

We have replaced our `TEST_IMAGE_NAME` string in `deployment.yaml` dynamically during CI.

Now you can apply this `deployment.yaml` from CI server, & it will update or push the deployment to **K8s** cluster wherever it's running.

**Note** :

if you want to store the config in repo also, you can commit back file from CI server repo, you have to store `3` deployment file, dev-`deploymentl.yaml`, `stag-deployment.yaml` if any changes in any branch you can commit that file from CI server to repo again and your YAML config will be saved in **repo** also.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Can you elaborate on the replacement portion? I.e., should I store the repalced/processed `deployment.yml` file as an artifact of the build and then use that artifact as the configuration for my Kubernetes cluster?

Comment: Why you want to store anything in artifacts ? Please correct me if missing anything, you have to deploy build when code commit to Dev branch and after that you tag or commit or release. 

In all cases GitHub will give you commit hash, you have to tag you docker image with commit hash and push same and same commit hash goes inside the deployment file in Image uri section.

Comment: Correct, but if I checkout the `deployment.yml` file from my repository, it will have the templated information in there. How do I get the templated `deployment.yml` file from my repository to my cluster with the correct tag information?

Comment: You have to add the step in CI after checkout, next step will replace the variable in ‘deployment.yaml’ this way image url will get set in deployment.yaml and from CI server you can simply apply that deployment.yaml file as it will be having the updated variables like image tag

Comment: i have shared my CI example file you check it once you will get the idea.

Comment: if you want to store the config in repo also, you can commit back file form CI server repo, you have to store 3 deployment file, dev-deploymentl.yaml, stag-deployment.yaml if any changes in any branch you can commit that file from CI server to repo again and your yaml config will be saved in repo also.

Comment: Committing a file back to the repository does not solve the original issue. That would create a new commit that is not the same as the tagged one. The Kubernetes cluster is running a machine that is different than the runner that is executing the build.

Comment: Commit deployment files to new branch which will only have config of K8s this way when you clone repo locally you will also get config yaml files.

Comment: In ideal scenario we don’t store config in repo just keep template of yaml in repo and use it to deploy application on k8s